# Android Studio Select item from SQLite database by spinner selection

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio, spinner

I am working on a project where I open up a random link in the browser after an imagebutton is pressed. I have created and populated a database table with different links and assigned them to categories. I would like to be able to filter which links are selected based upon a users' selection from a spinner dropdown. Right now, I am only able to select a random recipe from the database.

**This is the main activity with all the relevant methods (I have left out the import statements and any other unnecessary code :**

```
package com.example.randomrecipeapp;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//fields
ImageButton randomizer;
Spinner spinner_filter;
DatabaseHelper db;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    //connect fields
    randomizer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    //spinner things
    spinner_filter = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_filter);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner_filter.setAdapter(adapter);

    //initialize methods
    openRandomRecipe();

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//spinner response
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}

public void openRandomRecipe() {

    randomizer.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor res = db.getRandomData();

                    //if no data exists
                    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                        // show message
                        showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
                        return;
                    }

                    //add recipe link (columnIndex 1) to buffer sequence
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while (res.moveToNext()) {
                        buffer.append(res.getString(1));
                    }
                    //convert buffer to st
                    String sr = buffer.toString();
                    //open link in browser
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(sr)));

                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

**The openRandomRecipe() method calls this other method in my DatabaseHelper class:**

```
 //get one random recipe
public Cursor getRandomData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_RECIPES+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);
    return res;

}
```

Where TABLE_RECIPES is the name of the table. What I'm thinking I need to do is create a new method such as this:

```
public Cursor getRandomDataByCategory(String category) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+category+ " FROM "+TABLE_RECIPES+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);
    return res;
```

And then in the onClickListener in the MainActivity file do

```
Cursor res = db.getRandomData(category);
```

I'm just not sure how to figure out how to pull in the user selected item from the spinner into the getRandomData method. Is this even a correct way of solving this problem? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe he query would be along the lines of :-

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_category_column LIKE '%your_value%' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1
```

- where **your_table** represents the table name
- **your_value** represents the value select from the spinner
- The above assumes LIKE so if you had categories of Dinner and AfterDinner then selecting Dinner from the spinner would select from both (easy to change to = for a specific match).

Saying that I'd suggest that you could have a single getRandaomData method would suit both e.g. :-

```
public Cursor getRandomData(String category) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = null;
    String[] whereargs = null;
    if (category.length() > 0 ) {
        whereclause = COLUMN_RECIPES_CATEGORY + " LIKE ?";
        whereargs = new String[]{"%" + category + "%"};
    }
    return db.query(TABLE_RECIPES,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,"random()","1");
    //Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_RECIPES+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);
}
```

- This assumes that the category is never null (see working example), and also LIKE.

### WORKING EXAMPLE

The following is a working example based upon the code you have supplied (omitting (commenting out) code not necessary to demonstrate e.g. calling the next activity).

#### DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public static final String DBNAME = "recipee";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_RECIPES = "recipes";
    public static final String COLUMN_RECIPES_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_RECIPES_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_RECIPES_CATEGORY = "category";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDB = db;
        String crt_recipes_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_RECIPES + "(" +
                COLUMN_RECIPES_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COLUMN_RECIPES_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_RECIPES_CATEGORY + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_recipes_sql);
        addRecipee("Egg on Toast","Breakfast");
        addRecipee("Bangers and Mash", "Dinner");
        addRecipee("Cheese Sandwich","Snack");
        addRecipee("Mud Cake","Desert");
        addRecipee("Spaghetti Bolognaise","Dinner");
        addRecipee("Blueberry Cheesecake","Desert");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addRecipee(String name, String category) {
        if (mDB == null) {
            mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_RECIPES_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_RECIPES_CATEGORY,category);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_RECIPES,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getRandomData(String category) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String whereclause = null;
        String[] whereargs = null;
        if (category.length() > 0 ) {
            whereclause = COLUMN_RECIPES_CATEGORY + " LIKE ?";
            whereargs = new String[]{"%" + category + "%"};
        }
        return db.query(TABLE_RECIPES,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,"random()","1");
        //Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_RECIPES+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);
    }
}
```

- Note this adds a few recipes (with categories when the database is created)

### Strings.xml

i.e. just the Spinner items :-

```
<array name="category_array">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>C</item>
    <item>Dinner</item>
    <item>Breakfast</item>
    <item>Desert</item>
    <item>Snack</item>
</array>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //fields
    ImageButton randomizer;
    Spinner spinner_filter;
    TextView random_recipee;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    String current_category;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        random_recipee = this.findViewById(R.id.recipee);
        current_category = "";

        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        //connect fields
        randomizer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        //spinner things
        spinner_filter = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_filter);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner_filter.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner_filter.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                current_category = item.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        //initialize methods
        openRandomRecipe();
    }

    public void openRandomRecipe() {
        randomizer.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Cursor res = db.getRandomData(current_category);
                        random_recipee.setText("Nothing Found");
                        if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                            random_recipee.setText(
                                    "Recipee is " +res.getString(
                                            res.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RECIPES_NAME)
                                    ) +
                                            ". Category is " +
                                            res.getString(
                                                    res.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RECIPES_CATEGORY)
                                            )
                            );
                        }
                        res.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< should always close cursor when done with it.
                        return;
                        //add recipe link (columnIndex 1) to buffer sequence
                        //StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        /*
                        while (res.moveToNext()) {
                            buffer.append(res.getString(1));
                        }
                        */
                        //convert buffer to st
                        //String sr = buffer.toString();
                        //open link in browser
                        //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(sr)));

                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

- Note a TextView has been added that will show the selected recipe along with it's category.
- No image was used for the ImageButton

### Result

[image]

- Note Spinner clicked to show items

After clicking on the button with Dinner as the selected item :-

[image]

- Note as only 2 recipes with Dinner as the category clicking the button will often show the same recipe.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for the data I already had in the database. However, I'm unable to add data via the addRecipe statements you created. I have a separate activity that allows me to view the data in the table, and all I see are the previous recipes I added before posting this question. Have any idea why that might be?

Comment: You would have to tailor the addRecipe method to suit, the addRecipee method was written to enable addition via the onCreate method and relies upon the declaration the of mDB variable as a class variable as per `SQLiteDatabase mDB;`.  It may also not provide all the values that may be required, this would be dependant upon your schema. That is the example App was created purely to address the question you asked.